# Title Agencies that Accept Bitcoin?

Tags: contracts

Are there any title agencies that explicitly accept bitcoin, such as for buying houses, land, cars, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the country you are in. In Brazil there is a company that does accept bitcoin. http://www.tecnisa.com.br/bitcoin